# Custom post type, when type non existing post name, it query the nearest possible post name by default. How can I disabled this behavior

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

[image]

First, On a clean Wordpress installation using Local, I name the project "example" I install this Custom Post Type UI Plugin
Then I Activate it.

Then I have create a post type, suppose i name it "example".

[image]

Then I proceed to add this new custom post type "example" with post name "test"
[image]

I got this permalink, which works fine
http://example.local/example/test/

[image]

However, When I use link

http://example.local/example/t

I expected it to return some kind of page not found,
But it redirect to

http://example.local/example/test/

If i use link
http://example.local/example/a
However, It will correctly go to 404 page not found

[image]

I think I do lack some basic understanding.
How can I config it so when custom post type does not use exact existing post name
It will go to 404 page instead of go to nearest page.

Comment: this isn't specific to custom post types, it happens to all post types. Note that it should be redirecting to the canonical URL, so if you have SEO concerns then they are unfounded, Google should see that `http://example.local/example/t` has a canonical URL tag of `http://example.local/example/test` and that it 302 redirects, so there are no SEO penalties for duplicate content

Comment: Also questions about the custom post type UI plugin are offtopic here, 3rd party plugin/theme dev support questions are offtopic and not in this stacks scope. For help with the CPT UI plugin you should go to the CPT UI plugin forums or support

Comment: So there is nothing we can do about this right ?

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box, WordPress will try to be helpful and provide the next best post if it cannot find the one you specified - in your case `example/t`.

This feature can be deactivated, however:

```
function stop_404_guessing( $url ) {
    return ( is_404() ) ? false : $url;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'stop_404_guessing' );
```